# How do I access a user image?

Tags: users, 8, media

How can I access a user image in Drupal 8? I am trying to use this code, but I am getting an error.

```
$account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($q->uid); 
$name = $account->getUsername();        
$picture = $account->getUser_picture();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following snippet to get the user image.

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$picture = $user->get('user_picture')->entity->url();
```

If you want to get the default image when the user account doesn't have an image associated, use the following code.

```
$field = \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::loadByName('user', 'user', 'user_picture');
$default_image = $field->getSetting('default_image');
$file = \Drupal::entityManager()->loadEntityByUuid('file', $default_image['uuid']);
$picture = file_create_url($file->getFileUri());
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually worked for me.  A warning though, url() returns absolute URLs, and if you're in a drush script, you'll get something like `http://default/sites/default/files/pictures/2017-06/a.jpg`.