# How to get the user_picture styled

Tags: 8, users, entities, media

I have a $user and what to get the style image as a URL

originally found this answer [How do I access a user image?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217323/how-do-i-access-a-user-image/249513#249513)

but it was not what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this to work

```
Use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
$file_uri = $user->get('user_picture')->entity->getFileUri();
$styled_image_url = ImageStyle::load("large")->buildUrl($file_uri);
```